# Does Syncano has ability to handle import .xls?

Tags: angularjs, syncano

We want use Syncano to build a serverless app.
I can't find information about a handling .xls, so we need to import file from user and read parameters from him, like: number, name, price etc.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncano does not natively support .xls files and parsing that information, but you can simply convert it to a JSON *manually* using a site like this one: https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/

OR

You can use this http://faisalman.github.io/simple-excel-js/ in your **client-side** code to convert the file.

Also, you can store the file on Syncano, and then convert the .xls to JSON and parse it that way!

*[Disclaimer] I work for Syncano*